# IntentService with ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-service, android-dialog, android-service-binding

I'm performing long running (up to a minute) `File` read operation in an `IntentService` while showing a `ProgressDialog` in my `Activity`.

I do **not** publish progress, it's a simple *Please wait...* `Dialog`, only the final result needs to be passed to the `Activity`, which i do through a broadcast.

I have two problematic cases:

- The `Service` is running and the `Dialog` is showing. The user presses the Home button, putting the app in the background and the `Service` finishes while the app is in the background (showing the `Dialog`).

  I've solved this by registering/unregistering my `BroadcastReceiver` in `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`, instead of `onResume()` and `onPause()`. This way the app receives the finish broadcast even while being in the background, and dismisses the `Dialog`.
- The `Service` is running and the `Dialog` is showing while an **orientation change** happens. The `Service` obviously survives it, but the `Dialog` disappears.

  To solve this, i've added something like this to my `Service`:

  ```
  boolean running;

  public int isRunning() {
      return running;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      running = true;

      try {
          // doing stuff
      } catch (Exception e) {

      } finally {
          running = false;
      }
  }
  ```

  Then, in my `Activity` i bind to the `Service` after the orientation change in `onCreate()`, call `isRunning()` from `onServiceConnected()` and recreate the `Dialog` if the `Service` is still running.

My question is the same regarding both cases:

Is there a better approach to handle these situations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are binding to your service then you dont need any broadcasts: make two way communication via `Binder`, also instead of popping out `Dialog` use some more subtle indicator like `Notification` or indeterminate `ProgressBar` or something

Comment: @pskink Is Messaging required for the two way communication, or is it possible via a Binder? If so, how? Thank you.

Comment: read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)